# Send message to existing Actor in different project

Tags: scala, akka

I am wondering if it is possible to send message to an existing Actor from another project?

Existing Actor & allowed Messages:

```
package org.x.y.z
private case object MA
private case object MB
private class ExistActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case MA =>
    case MB =>    
  }
}
```

However my current project is different from the above, it's `org.w.h.i`, for example.

Suppose I know the actorSystem name, url and everything that is needed to construct an `ActorSelection` of `org.x.y.ExistActor`, So is it possible to send a message and get results?

Note the allowed message of `org.x.y.ExistActor` and itself are all private, if I am sending a message, I would make a local copy of allowed messages.

Comment: do you mean JVM/host instead of project? `org.w.h.i` is a package which could be in the same project or not.

Comment: probably, remote actors is what you are looking for. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov, different JVM, different host as well as different Project, it's an open source project, I can see the source code, and want to communicate with it

Comment: @YaduKrishnan, Yep, I am using remote actors, but cannot make sure if it is possible to send message of type org.w.h.i.MA and get response, probably not possible i think...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if both systems are set up for remoting you can send a message to any actor that you know the path for using `ActorSelection`.

However, unless your remote actor system is able to send messages that your actor will respond do, addressing it (as in your example) will be pointless.

Comment: What if I send a Message of type `org.w.h.i.MA` to the remote actor, will it response? or should I use reflection to get `org.x.y.z.MA` because it a private one?

Comment: No, `org.w.h.i.MA` and `org.x.y.z.MA` are completely unrelated, so your actor would not respond.  Why does that message have to be private?

Comment: It was an existing open source system's actor I want to communicate with, and the messages have been made private to the package. Is that possible i use reflection and construct messages manually?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Akka Remoting should be enabled on both JVMs obviously. Once you successfully get `ActorSelection` you can send messages to that actor. It does not matter whether the actor is defined as `private class`. All that matters that it's running and accessible.

Now the question is whether the actor would accept the messages that you send and whether you can construct these messages since they are private in your case.

It all depends on a serializer configured for Akka Remoting. See [these docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/serialization.html) for config options and check whether remote project uses serializer that does not depend on Java serialization or any class version specific serialization.

*By default Akka Remoting uses [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf) so that should allow you to construct messages of exactly same type and shape on your side and send them over successfully.*

Comment: How will protocol buffer serialise my message? won't it also attach the full qualified class name?